# Find a item in a list using linq

Tags: linq

Using LINQ, from a List csvLines, how can I find an item  using multiple values? I would like to find the item that has dog in the first column and "black" in the third column.

```
List<string[]> csvLines = new List<string[]>();
csvLines.Add(new string[] { "dog", "walk", "black" });
csvLines.Add(new string[] { "dog", "run", "brown" });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var found =
    from line in csvLines
    where line[0] == "dog"
    where line[2] == "black"
    select line;
```

From your data I get:

[image: found]